# Is it possible to get HTML page of any URI with angular?

Tags: angular, web-scraping, web-crawler

Good day,

Is it possible to get any uri(page) contents with Angular. For example : https://linkedin.com. I know that this is a backend side task.
Just want to know is it possible to do with Angular.

Regards

Comment: Finally I do scraping with selenium, don't understand why I get 2 minus..

Answer (score 0):

You can make a cross domain GET request, and it's depends upon the remote server if it will return an HTML response. Most web servers will honor a GET request that doesn't have modified headers or a body.

```
this.httpClient.get<string>('http://linked.com').subscribe(value=>console.log(value));
```

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. @cgtag

Comment: @alytvynov then that web server does not allow cross domain GET requests for that URL. You'll have to use a proxy that isn't subject to a CORS policy.